# Annihilator of annihilator of subspace in dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be  a real linear space, 
$X'$ be a set of all linear functional on $X$.

For $V\subset X$, $L\subset X'$ we define:
$$
V^\bot=\{f\in X': f(x)=0 \textrm{ for } x\in V \},
$$
$$
L_\bot=\{x\in X: f(x)=0 \textrm{ for } f\in L \}.
$$

I know that $L \subset (L_\bot)^\bot$.
Is it true that $(L_\bot)^\bot=L$ ?

Comment: This question might be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286108/s-subseteq-v-rightarrow-textspans-cong-s00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always true if $X$ is not finite dimensional.

If $X$ is finite dimensional, what can you say about the dimensions?