# Annihilators in dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be  a real linear space,
$X'$ be a set of all linear functional on $X$.

For $V\subset X$, $L\subset X'$ we define:
$$
V^\bot=\{f\in X': f(x)=0 \textrm{ for } x\in V \},
$$
$$
L_\bot=\{x\in X: f(x)=0 \textrm{ for } f\in L \}.
$$

We have for linear subspace $L\subset X'$ that $L \subset (L_\bot)^\bot$.

How to describe the set $(L_\bot)^\bot$ in the case when $X$ is of infinite dimension?

Comment: I believe that the answer to this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286108/s-subseteq-v-rightarrow-textspans-cong-s00 is what you need, or at least very very close to it.

Comment: The description of the (pre)-annihilator is a general one which can viewed on any vector space and does not change by the dimension of the underlying space. However in the infinite case it's way more interesting to look at it as one has very powerful tools to determine whether subspaces are dense/closed/weak* closed etc. using the Hahn-Banach, Banach-Dieudonne and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the annihilator as above does not involve any reference to a dependence on dimensionality. Thus you would only substitute the V by L⊥ in the first defintion. But I guess you mean something different. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: If $dim X =n<\infty$ it is easy to prove that $(L_\bot)^\bot=L$: $L \subset (L_\bot)^\bot$ and both have the same dimension.